# How can I use button to play a sound with ListView?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to add a button in `ListView` to play sound. The problem is the IDE (in List.java) cannot resolve this method
`mediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.people);`

**The MainActivity.java code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("item1");


        //instantiate custom adapter
        List adapter = new List(list, this);

        //handle listview and assign adapter
        ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**The List.java code:**

```
public class List extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;
     MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    public List(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return list.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners

        Button addBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);


        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.people);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you import some other MediaPlayer class?

Comment: i only import  import android.media.MediaPlayer;   and i  initialize the MediaPlayer and it still have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method signature is `MediaPlayer create (Context context, int resid)`

`View.OnClickListener` is not a `Context`, which is what `this` is in that case. `BaseAdapter` is also not a `Context`.

You can declare it in the adapter using `MediaPlayer.create(List.this.context, R.raw.people)`

Comment: Thank you it works but the sound doesn't played. i tried to use to use  MediaPlayer.Perpare(); inside try and catch block but it still not working

Comment: Not sure what to tell you other than to check that your sound file is not corrupt. Since this answer has resolved the issue in the question, you may accept it and post another one.

Comment: OK.Thank You for your help.

Comment: i can't i am a  beginner in this site

Comment: That does not prevent you from accepting the answer. You don't have enough reputation to upvote. That is different.

Comment: @abdelrhman Please [follow this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to learn to accept